# Chosen Select with two dropdownlist

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Idea is that you select ddlMoo and it triggers ajax function and binds ddlFoo.
This was working until I added chosen-select functionality now chosen select doesn't bind his own list. dropdownlists are still fine but unchoosable.

```
    <div id="divMoo" runat="server">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMoo" runat="server" Width="300px" class="chosen-select">
            </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div id="divFoo" runat="server" style="display: none;">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFoo" runat="server" Width="300px" class="chosen-select">
            </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>


<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        ChosenSelect();
    });

    function ChosenSelect() {
        $('.chosen-select').chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });
        //resize the chosen on window resize
        $(window).on('resize.chosen', function () {
            var w = $('.chosen-select').parent().width();
            $('.chosen-select').next().css({ 'width': w });
        }).trigger('resize.chosen');
    }

    $('#<%= ddlMoo.ClientID %>').on('change', function () {
        FooList(this.value);
        ChosenSelect();
    });

    function FooList(MooId) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Foo.aspx/Foo",
            data: "{ 'MooId': '" + MooId+ "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                $("#<%= divFoo.ClientID %>").show();

                if (data.d.length > 1)
                    $("#<%= ddlFoo.ClientID %>").html($('<option></option>').val("").html("Choose.."))

                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    $("#<%= ddlFoo.ClientID %>").append($('<option></option>').val(data.d[i].FooId).html(data.d[i].FooName));
                }

                if (data.d.length == 1)
                    $("#<%= ddlFoo.ClientID %>").change();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `$("#<%= Foo.ClientID %>").change();`.. which one is Foo?

Comment: Foo second(invisible) one. that triggers .on('change', function () of Foos for some other unrelated reason. I didn't add that change method due to decrease code length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your chosen call finishes before it can find any element and also there are a lot of places where you can make your code better -

**One** Wrong Placement of codes

The first chosen call is okay but why the other codes are outside `document.ready`? you should keep them inside `document.ready` -

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    ChosenSelect();

    function ChosenSelect() {
        $('.chosen-select').chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });
        //resize the chosen on window resize
        $(window).on('resize.chosen', function () {
            var w = $('.chosen-select').parent().width();
            $('.chosen-select').next().css({ 'width': w });
        }).trigger('resize.chosen');
    }

    $('#<%= ddlMoo.ClientID %>').on('change', function () {
        FooList(this.value);
        ChosenSelect();
    });

    .......
});
```

**Two** The 2nd call is not okay and reason why chosen cannot see items in list -

```
$('#<%= ddlMoo.ClientID %>').on('change', function () {
    FooList(this.value);
    ChosenSelect();
});
```

Why? Because `FooList` is an ajax call and the execution **does not stop** there. So, before the ajax can fetch all the entries and populate then inside the drop down list, chosen is called before it is done and it will show empty list. You have 2 choices, either call chosen inside `success` callback or if you want to keep the current chosen call, then you have to notify `chosen` that you have updated the list by calling `updated` callback method. I will go with the one that calls `chosen` list update method, add this call inside the success method -

```
function FooList(MooId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Foo.aspx/Foo",
        data: "{ 'MooId': '" + MooId+ "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            $("#<%= divFoo.ClientID %>").show();

            if (data.d.length > 1)
                $("#<%= ddlFoo.ClientID %>").html($('<option></option>').val("").html("Choose.."))

            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                $("#<%= ddlFoo.ClientID %>").append($('<option></option>').val(data.d[i].FooId).html(data.d[i].FooName));
            }

            if (data.d.length == 1)
                $("#<%= ddlFoo.ClientID %>").change();


           //update chosen list 
           $("#<%= ddlFoo.ClientID %>").trigger("chosen:updated");
        }
    });
}
```

but remember in older version of chosen the event was called `liszt:updated`, and in newer version it is called `chosen:updated`. Make change as necessary

**Three** I really don't understand why are you using server side `div`with `runat='server'`. That is a very bad idea and totally unnecessary. You are just overpopulating the view state and making asp.net do a lot more works, which it really don't need to do.

Comment: Four > I changed the code to make it simple I mischanged that Foo must be ddlFoo. I'll edit to correct that now.

Comment: $("#<%= divFoo.ClientID %>").trigger("chosen:updated"); Is worked! thank you for your help!

Comment: Three > I change visibilities depend on action on code behind. That why I use runat="server"

Comment: I couldn't understand why One and Two are not okey. I didn't change them but code works. I'll try to understand your point.

Comment: Three > I am not sure about using code behind, may be you have good reason, but remember that, whenever you use a server side control you are slowing the page rendering, because ASP.Net does a lot of processing for each server side control. So you should minimize the use of server side controls.